# Python str object does not support item assignment when replacing array values

Tags: python, arrays, sockets

It gives me an error when I try to replace part of the data.
I wanted to replace the hex value of a part of the data before it is sent back.
How should I approach this?

```
data, addr = s.recvfrom(32768)
if knownClient is None:
    knownClient = addr
if addr == knownClient:
    s.sendto(data, knownServer)
    print "Sent     : " + ":".join("{0:02X}".format(ord(c)) for c in data)
else:
    data[10] = 0xFF #error_here
    data[11] = 0x0A #error_here
    s.sendto(data, knownClient)
```

Comment: Is `data` a `string`, `tuple`, `list`, or `array`?

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee: It's a string, assuming `s` is a Python socket.  http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify strings - they're immutable.  If you want to change the string, you have several options.  The first option is to make a new string.

```
data = data[:10]+chr(0xFF) + chr(0x0A) + data[12:]
```

If you will be modifying the data frequently, you may want to use a list or array instead

```
datalist = list(data)
datalist[10] = chr(0xFF)
datalist[11] = chr(0x0A)
```

Then when you want to get back to a string after modifications:

```
data = ''.join(datalist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a new string:

```
data = data[:10] + chr(0xFF) + data[11:]
```